# LoadError for HTTPClient on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to run a Ruby script from the Command Prompt on a PC with Windows 7 installed and am running into the following error:

`C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- httpclient (LoadError)`

I've explicitly added this block in the code and it looks like it's successfully installed right before this using:

```
begin
  gem "httpclient"
rescue LoadError
  system("gem install httpclient")
  Gem.clear_paths
end
```

Right before the error I get the following output:

```
Successfully installed httpclient-2.6.0.1
Parsing documentation for httpclient-2.6.0.1
Done installing documentation for httpclient after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I haven't done anything using Ruby on Windows before, so hopefully I'm missing something really small.  Just another note, I'm using Mechanize and Nokogiri as well, hence Ruby version `2.0.0`.

Edit: Apparently this isn't just an issue with the `HTTPClient` gem.  This same error occurs for whatever gem is in the first `require` statement.

Edit #2: I believe it has something to do with having multiple versions of Ruby on my PC.  I'm trying to run it using Ruby version `2.0.0-x64` but it looks like it's looking for gems in the `2.2.0` directories.

Any help is appreciated on getting this to work!

Comment: you need to set your `PATH` correctly

Comment: I've set it in `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> variables for User` with the `Path` variable reading `C:\Ruby 200-x64\bin` and still no luck.  Is there anywhere else I'm supposed to be changing it?

Comment: Doh.  Needed to exit out of the Command Prompt and restart it back up.  This seemed to fix it and get it working!  Thanks!

Comment: `where.exe gem` can be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to set my `Path` variable in `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> variables for User` to `C:\Ruby 200-x64\bin` and then restart my Command Prompt.  After that and installing the necessary gems, everything worked as expected!